# Most questions have already been asked, can't think of anything new to ask

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, reputation, upvotes

> This is kind of related to the [Fastest Gun in the West problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), except it's for questions instead of answers.

Many of the most common programming questions have already been asked and answered:

- [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)
- [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-page-redirect-using-jquery)
- [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring)
- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)
- [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

That's a good thing, since users can easily find solutions to their problems.

But with so many questions that've been asked and answered, tons of new questions are being closed as duplicates. Since the most basic questions have already been asked, only very specific and unique questions won't get closed as duplicates. Unfortunately, if they're very specific and unique, they're in danger of being closed as *too localized*.

Extremely specific and unique questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888781/how-can-i-force-sbt-to-keep-searching-repositories-until-it-finds-a-jar-with-spe
- [identify records in one dataset that are in between times in another data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888764/identify-records-in-one-dataset-that-are-in-between-times-in-another-data-set)
- [Insert values in gridview manually using textboxes,loops? ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888784/insert-values-in-gridview-manually-using-textboxes-loops-asp-net-c-sharp)

The more specific and unique a question is, the less likely other users are going to know the exact answer to that particular question.

**But those really basic questions, almost anyone can ask. It's just that they asked them first, and they get all the credit (upvotes).**

Will a time come when 99% of all programming problems are solved, and there's barely any room for questions that aren't too localized? I can't think of anything to ask, and I desperately need rep!

> *The real issue people are missing here in all the answers and comments is: Whenever a question/answer is the "first one" posted regarding a specific common problem, that question gets loaded with votes throughout the years, even the most simple ones So the advantage is really the first questions and answers. The more time goes by, the less common problems are reported that most users search for. I have seen many users with massive reputation that barely know how to spell in english, when I check their profile I see they have a couple of questions that got many upvotes throughout the years. – user5890979 Sep 6 '17 at 23:35*

Comment: 1) "too localized" isn't a close option anymore 2) There is always new technology(See: IOS 10, ...) so there are always new questions.

Comment: Unlikely, there are always new programming languages and libraries.

Comment: *I desperately need rep!* - For what?

Comment: That "all" questions have already been asked is not the problem.  That questioners don't have enough imagination is.  Too many of them think it can only happens to them and won't consider finding the other programmers it happened to.  The only way a Q+A web site can ever get to 13,000 questions per day.

Comment: "Everything that can be invented has been invented." - C.H.Duell, 1899

Comment: *I desperately need rep!* --> http://stackoverflow.com/documentation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not entirely true.

[image: questions per day]

Ever since SO's inception, the questions per day rate has been consistently on the increase (besides the occasional and temporary drop).

It may seem like everything that can be asked today has been asked. Then stop looking at today, and start looking at tomorrow, and the days, weeks, months and years that follow.

What happens when a library pushes a new release, or a language gets a new version, or a new operating system or language is released? Suddenly there's a whole new range of questions available to ask.

So, got nothing to ask? That's okay. Take an hour, bake some cookies. By the time they're done, out there somewhere in this big network of development, someone will have changed an ecosystem.

Comment: Looking at the chart there is *insane* number of answers that could have happened - good 40K/week answers are missing if number of answers did not stop to grow around 2014. Definitely plenty of reputation to make for at least couple people ;)

Answer (score 13):

> Will a time come when 99% of all programming problems are solved, and there's barely any room for questions that aren't too localized?

Yes, if people would just quit making new stuff that has new problems.

We're nowhere near question saturation. It's not a thing to worry about yet.

Comment: Even new stuff with no problems requires questions about how to use it.

Comment: And IF we get to such a point where every programming question has been asked and answered (let's assume that it is achievable).... Then hasn't stack succeeded in its goal?

Answer (score 4):

Having used Stack Overflow for quite a while, though passively (not actively asking/answering questions), I have come to see that many NEW users (including myself for a while) do seem to have this outlook.

But as I have become a stronger programmer and thus come to have different and more specialized questions, this belief has faded.  Now I can see that I used to have this belief since the basic, and broad questions about Java and C++ applied to me then.  Those were the only questions I knew how to ask since they were the only I had then.  It seemed like I had nothing to ask since every question I ever thought of was answered back then. Instead, now that I am a stronger programmer, I am now thinking of more specialized questions, of which there are near infinitely many.

I can tell that it is newer users with less programming experience who have the general and low level questions who still hold the belief that there is nothing to ask.  Sure those broad questions that will apply to many in each field have been asked, but there are plenty of questions for when they become stronger programmers in a subject.