# Why am I getting punished for asking specialized questions?

Tags: support, post-ban

So I'm getting this message:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

I understand the quality issue. However, when I scroll over my questions, I think that they are not "well-received" because they are somewhat specialized. Why? Because I usually find answers for not specialized questions because I actually read "Questions that may already have your answer" and "Similiar Questions", even now, and don't find anything matching. (Also [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326391/most-questions-have-already-been-asked-cant-think-of-anything-new-to-ask).) I have two duplicates so far where I failed to do that, imo because the original didn't show up. 3 questions have valid answers and 7 are really still open, as no answer was found by me or anyone else so far.

The problem now is the following: I don't get an upvote for specialized, yet sometime [extensive questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674760/program-runs-fine-in-ide-but-not-in-jar-because-akka-config-is-not-properly-load) but a warning for that, while someone learning to use loops gets [upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358196/generalizing-an-algorithm) (at the time I answered, the question was at +3). This is frustrating.

So what do you suggest? Is there anything I can do?

- As I see it, my questions are very clear (e.g. Q: ["[is] there is
  already a built-in functionality to automatically set all
  elements/attributes to required=false as a default?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845450/simple-xml-framework-nothing-required-by-default); A: nobody
  seems to know), but if you have any idea for editing some of them,
  please let me know?
- Or should I just don't use tags so intensively
  (as they are supposed to be used imo) to attract more attention?
- Maybe I shouldn't ask questions here even if I think they could be interesting for others and instead bug the devs directly in hope of a reply? I actually already do that, too, sometimes, if my question was already asked and received no satisfying answers for months.

**EDIT:** I don't have any recently deleted questions or answers, and according to [this post about 0-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276347/how-do-zero-score-questions-impact-a-question-ban) that couldn't be it either. **So what is the exact reason for the warning again?**

Nevertheless, the comments are quite helpful and I can only recommend the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and will use it to formulate and also edit my questions in the future.

**EDIT:** This post is a duplicate. Before I would have said it's the fault of SO not showing that one in "Similiar questions" etc., but now I'm wiser and know that I haven't searched long enough :-)

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions that were down voted?

Comment: I've seen this excuse presented before, that you are getting blocked from asking additional questions because your previous questions were highly specialized, but the excuse just doesn't hold water. There are *tons* of specialized questions asked on the site, and the people who ask them don't get post-banned. In every case, it turns out that either the person has some deleted questions that they're trying to hide, or the questions are just low-quality. In either case, the quality control is working as intended. Certainly doesn't seem to me that Java + XML questions are "specialized"...

Comment: See also: [How do Zero-Score Questions Impact a Question Ban?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276347/how-do-zero-score-questions-impact-a-question-ban)

Comment: An important rule: Always include a minimal reproducible example in your question. You are much less likely to receive downvotes if you do that and such an example is always appreciated (might even get you upvotes).

Comment: I've looked over some of your questions and I can only say that some of the questions can use an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and scrutinized before posting by scoring against the [Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @rene I don't know about deleted questions (I forget a lot of things), where can I look that up?

Comment: Yes, failing to remember mistakes from the past is one of the major reasons for users getting into a ban ...

Comment: @CodyGray Okay, but it was less an excuse and more the only explanation I had. I want to improve my understanding of how this site works and apparently asking here was the right thing to do, as I seem to have a false understanding about something I'm still figuring out.

Comment: @rene That much is obvious. I may be new to SE, but not to communities in the internet. Usually there is a reminder for past mistakes somewhere as long as they can be hold against one, maybe you know where?

Comment: There was a reminder/warning. It's the message you received, and quoted above. It says that you are *in danger*, not that you have been blocked.

Comment: Check your recent deleted answers/questions in your profile, as explained [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269839/search-for-own-deleted-answer).

Comment: @rene So I don't have any recently deleted. I'm thankful for the rich advice, but my question here remains unanswered for the time being, I'm afraid.

Comment: You have 1 deleted question, 2 questions with a -1 score and no question with a positive score. Yeah, you're *tending towards* an overall negative. Which is what the warning is warning you about. You should take extra care to produce really good questions from here on out.

Comment: A quick review of your questions show for the most part they are all marginal at best and most are too-broad, opinion based, lack any code or are "help me figure this out by reading the documentation for me" ( Recommendations ). The system is working correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not getting *punished*; you are given yet another opportunity to learn from your mistakes made earlier, so you can improve your contributions **BEFORE** you hit the actual question ban.

Recovering from a [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) is not impossible, but it is [hard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313637/on-average-how-often-do-users-redeem-themselves-from-a-post-ban-of-either-kind/313641#313641).

Let's have a quick look at your current [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6430269/greenthor?tab=questions):

[image: Questions]

You notice the two questions that are duplicate. There is a reason that both [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648) start with the advice to research before you ask. Doing the research has two benefits:

- you might find your answer
- you can include what you found and explain why it doesn't work in your context

Next we find this comment from you:

> I was concentrating to much on coding and though just to throw this question into the room. I'm sorry I forgot about the guidelines, really need to think my questions through...

But that realization was short-lived when you asked [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343873/how-to-parse-dates-with-varying-formats-with-java-time).

That example also shows another habit of the the questions you ask. Most of them seem to be about code, but at best we get paragraphs of text, with a scattered line of code. Stack Overflow is about coding issues. [Minimal, Complete, verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are a key in that.

Let me take on example where you probably think [this is very specialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125283/why-did-the-local-akka-remote-connection-fail). I don't think it is. Diagnosing issues in client-server stuff is already hard as it is. Without the code and configuration you used to run into those log messages, how on earth should I reproduce that? What do you expect from those who answer: To create an example them selves? Or do you want them to take a guess at it? If they do, they run the risk of getting downvotes.

**tl;dr** there is no punishment going on. It is still a fact that upvotes are far more common than downvotes. Failing to get upvotes indicates issues with the post. Asking questions that are duplicates is just a waste of the little time we have. Providing enough context is key so users might have an easy go at answering your question. Keep in mind that we are not here to help you specifically; the Q/A pair should be beneficial for future visitors as well.

Comment: thanks for your efforts and really big thank you for making me realize the opportunity I have :D